# Image as plane only visible from certain angles

Tags: materials, objects, shaders, image, transparency

Sorry I'm really new to this  program still but I've had the issue where image planes are only seen from a certain angle for a while and I don't know how to fix it yet.In case it helps to know there's a purple plane , then the picture and then a transparent plane on top.

[image][image]

Comment: there must be faces overlapping, move your plane a little bit

Comment: I tried to move  it very far away to check but I cant even see  it from any angle now :(

Comment: please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file (copy the link it will give you and paste it here): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I didn't get any link but i looked for the .blend file  with the same name , I hope  it was right.If it wasn't I feel bad so don't worry ill try to just  figure  out something.

Comment: [How to share a Blend file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file)

Comment: the link will appear in the URL field

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/b4442a5293ad439e96d6caa0868dabc9

Comment: It's a sorting problem from using Alpha Blend. Set the materials' Blender Mode to opaque.

Comment: @scurest that makes the  image underneath not visible  at  all anymore ,unless  im missing something obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as moonboots already said, select the image, press G Y and move it just a little bit to -y (you can hold shift during moving to move it slowly).

Then you get:

[image]

Comment: Alright thank you!!

Comment: If my answer works for u please check the checkmark left to my answer. Thanks.